# Move all zeroes to the beginning of a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list like below:

```
a = [4, 5, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 1, 0, 5]
```

and I want to push all zeroes to the beginning of that list. The result must be like below.

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 5]
```

How to do it in Python 2?

Comment: does the order matter??? if not you can just a.sort().

Answer (score 16):

You could sort the list:

```
a.sort(key=lambda v: v != 0)
```

The `key` function tells Python to sort values by wether or not they are `0`. `False` is sorted before `True`, and values are then sorted based on their original relative position.

For `0`, `False` is returned, sorting all those values first. For the rest `True` is returned, leaving sort to put them last but leave their relative positions untouched.

Demo:

```
>>> a = [4, 5, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 1, 0, 5]
>>> a.sort(key=lambda v: v != 0)
>>> a
[0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 5]
```

Comment: Is there any guarantee that the sort is stable? The language docs don't mention it as far as I can tell.

Comment: @viraptor: yes, the sort is guaranteed to be stable.

Comment: @viraptor: see [Is python's sorted() function guaranteed to be stable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1915376)

Comment: I like the simplicity of this approach, but for larger lists keep in mind that sorting algorithms usually have computational time complexity __n ln n__. Moving all zeros to the end of list should be possible in linear time (__n__) - see other answers.

Comment: @Messa: note that that solution loops through the list *twice* though. Once for the `a.count(0)` call, a second for the filtered list comprehension. The cost of the list multiplication and the concatenations also need to be factored in. In *practice*, I expect the sort to win.

Answer (score 11):

This can be done without sorting.

### Solutions

Initialization:

```
In [8]: a = [4, 5, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 1, 0, 5]

In [9]: from itertools import compress, repeat, chain
```

`list.count` and [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress)

```
In [10]: x = [0] * a.count(0); x.extend(compress(a, a))

In [11]: x
Out[11]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 5]
```

Same as before, but without `list.count`

```
In [12]: c = list(compress(a, a)); [0] * (len(a) - len(c)) + c
Out[12]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 5]
```

`list.count`, [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress), [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat), [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
In [13]: list(chain(repeat(0, a.count(0)), compress(a, a)))
Out[13]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 5]
```

Same as the previous one, but without `list.count`

```
In [14]: c = list(compress(a, a)); list(chain(repeat(0, len(a) - len(c)), c))
Out[14]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 5]
```

### Benchmarks

For small lists:

```
In [21]: %timeit x = [0] * a.count(0); x.extend(compress(a, a))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 583 ns per loop

In [22]: %timeit c = list(compress(a, a)); [0] * (len(a) - len(c)) + c
1000000 loops, best of 3: 661 ns per loop

In [23]: %timeit list(chain(repeat(0, a.count(0)), compress(a, a)))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 762 ns per loop

In [24]: %timeit c = list(compress(a, a)); list(chain(repeat(0, len(a) - len(c)), c))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 900 ns per loop
```

For large lists:

```
In [28]: a *= 10000000

In [29]: %timeit x = [0] * a.count(0); x.extend(compress(a, a))
1 loops, best of 3: 1.43 s per loop

In [30]: %timeit c = list(compress(a, a)); [0] * (len(a) - len(c)) + c
1 loops, best of 3: 1.37 s per loop

In [31]: %timeit list(chain(repeat(0, a.count(0)), compress(a, a)))
1 loops, best of 3: 1.79 s per loop

In [32]: %timeit c = list(compress(a, a)); list(chain(repeat(0, len(a) - len(c)), c))
1 loops, best of 3: 1.47 s per loop
```

As you can see, in some cases `itertools`-based solutions tend to be slower, because of the big number of function calls.

Comment: What does it do when the list contains `None` or `False`? :)

Comment: `None` and `False` are falsy, so all of them will be replaced with zeros. But the original list contains only numbers, so I don't think this a problem.

Comment: Another option would be `x = [0] * a.count(0); x += compress(a, a)`, which happens to be faster in all cases on my machine.  That said, your benchmark isn't really fair since `sorted(a, ...)` is slower than `a.sort(...)` due to the additional copy of the list, and you would use `key=bool` instead of `key=lambda x: x != 0` if you were trying to optimise for speed.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some better timings, with two new methods:

```
SETUP="
from itertools import compress, repeat, chain
a = [4, 5, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 1, 0, 5]
"
```

First the sorting:

```
python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "a.sort(key=bool)"
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.51 usec per loop
```

Then frostnational's methods:

```
python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "list(chain(repeat(0, a.count(0)), compress(a, a)))"
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.16 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "cs = list(compress(a, a)); list(chain(repeat(0, len(a)-len(cs)), cs))"
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.37 usec per loop
```

Then methods more directly working from lists:

```
python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "[0] * a.count(0) + list(filter(bool, a))"
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "nonzero = list(filter(bool, a)); [0] * (len(a)-len(nonzero)) + nonzero"
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.87 usec per loop
```

And again with larger sized input:

```
SETUP="
from itertools import compress, repeat, chain
a = [4, 5, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 1, 0, 5] * 1000
"
```

Sorting:

```
python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "a.sort(key=bool)"
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.08 msec per loop
```

frostnational's:

```
python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "list(chain(repeat(0, a.count(0)), compress(a, a)))"
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 333 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "cs = list(compress(a, a)); list(chain(repeat(0, len(a)-len(cs)), cs))"
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 206 usec per loop
```

New:

```
python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "[0] * a.count(0) + list(filter(bool, a))"
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 295 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "nonzero = list(filter(bool, a)); [0] * (len(a)-len(nonzero)) + nonzero"
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 143 usec per loop
```

That said, despite being relatively slow, Martijn Pieters' decision to use sorting is actually pretty competitive for reasonably-sized lists and premature optimisation is the root of all evil.

---

FWIW, here are some timings for very long lists:

```
SETUP="
from itertools import compress, repeat, chain
a = [4, 5, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 1, 0, 5] * 1000000
"
python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "a.sort(key=bool)"
# 10 loops, best of 3: 1.21 sec per loop

python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "list(chain(repeat(0, a.count(0)), compress(a, a)))"
# 10 loops, best of 3: 347 msec per loop

python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "cs = list(compress(a, a)); list(chain(repeat(0, len(a)-len(cs)), cs))"
# 10 loops, best of 3: 226 msec per loop

python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "[0] * a.count(0) + list(filter(bool, a))"
# 10 loops, best of 3: 310 msec per loop

python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "nonzero = list(filter(bool, a)); [0] * (len(a)-len(nonzero)) + nonzero"
# 10 loops, best of 3: 153 msec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this simple process:-

```
from collections import deque
a = [4, 5, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 1, 0, 5]
b = deque([x for x in a if x!=0])
for i in a:
    if i==0:
        b.appendleft(0)
print list(b)
#output -> [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 5]
```