# Python: Sort multidimensional list, but respecting internal incrementer

Tags: python, sorting, csv

This might be a rather simple question - but I'm relatively new to python in my defense! 
Here's the case - I have loaded a CSV file into a list which looks something like this:

```
["4567", "59.0000", 7.0000", "1"]
["4567", "59.0000", 7.0000", "2"]
["4567", "59.0000", 7.0000", "5"]
["1234", "59.0000", 7.0000", "1"]
["1234", "59.0000", 7.0000", "2"]
["1234", "59.0000", 7.0000", "3"]
```

The first column is a unique id - where the last is number in the sequence which needs to be preserved (root of my problem).

I would like to order by the unique id (first row), but keep the sequences in order. So I would rather have the list like this

```
["1234", "59.0000", 7.0000", "1"]
["1234", "59.0000", 7.0000", "2"]
["1234", "59.0000", 7.0000", "3"]
["4567", "59.0000", 7.0000", "1"]
["4567", "59.0000", 7.0000", "2"]
["4567", "59.0000", 7.0000", "5"]
```

Obviously when I just sort on the unique id - the sequences gets messed up.

Is this a simple task to do all in one, or do I need to loop through the list twice? How can it be done? I'm pretty clueless. Thanks for your time!

Comment: So the question is: "How to sort by multiple values?"

Answer (score 1):

This question appears to be "How to sort by multiple values?"

If this is so, see [How To: Sorting](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) which covers this and most other cases. The basic approach is to use the `key` function to *return a tuple*, as tuples are orderable in Python.

```
# sort by 1st column, then 4th column (both as integer values)
sorted(rows, key = lambda r: (int(r[0]), int(r[3]))
```

Now, even if there *wasn't* the 4th column (or if it is the *order* of the row and not the value of the 4th column that matters), we could still use the fact that [`sorted` uses is a stable sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915376/is-pythons-sorted-function-guaranteed-to-be-stable). This means that for any items/rows that compare equivalently the ordering is preserved. Thus the following has the same result (for the given data) as the first sort:

```
# sort by 1st column (as integer); preserve the "row order" by stability
sorted(rows, key = lambda r: int(r[0]))
```

Comment: `sorted(l,key=lambda x:int(x[0],int[x[3]]))`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a class instead of a list of lists.  But you could also use a key in your sort (sorted is slower than list_.sort()) or (temporarily) change the order of your sublists' elements.