# Sort numeric lines with thousand separators

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x, numeric

I want to sort a list starting with numbers (using Python3).
A lot of these numbers are with thousand separators (dots) and decimals (commas).

extract of mylist:

```
mylist = ['23 text', '23.130', '12 text', '1.482 text', '3,25']
```

I tried this:
**Numeric sorting**:

`sorted(mylist, key=int, reverse=True)` --> gives a 'not an integer' error

I tried this also:
**Alphanumeric sorting**:

```
convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text
alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert(c) for c in regex.split('([0-9]+)', key) ]
mysort.sort( key=alphanum_key, reverse=True )
```

***Alphanumeric output***:

```
['23.130', '23 text', '12 text', '3,25', '1.482 text']
```

***expected output***:

```
['3,25', '12 text', '23 text', '1.482 text', '23.130']
```

How can I sort my list with the expected output?

### **EDIT**

If there are strings with only text p.e.

```
mylist = ['2 another test', '4,32', '801', '4apples', 'foo', '4,32 hi', 'apples4', '', '13.300 a test', '2apples', 'doo', '12 today']
```

I would like the output as below (including the empty fields):

```
['2 another test', '2apples', '4apples', '4,32', '4,32 hi', '12 today', '801', '13.300 a test', 'apples4', 'doo', 'foo', '']
```

Comment: Take a look at the natsort library. Not sure if it is what you need for this particular situation, but there is a good chance it will.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: natsort gives this as output: `['1.482 text', '3,25', '12 text', '23 text', '23.130']`

Comment: Did you set the localization parameters correctly? Because it uses American decimal and thousands separator, which are the opposite of the notation you are using.

Comment: http://pythonhosted.org/natsort/examples.html#locale-aware-sorting-human-sorting

Comment: Double and triple checked your use-case. Going to submit an issue to `natsort`. It should be able to handle this after doing something like `import locale; locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'german')`, but does not work correctly as you said.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I first installed naturalsort but it was not the right one. then I installed natsort. Now with natsort installed it doesn't recognize the module `from natsort import natsorted
ImportError: cannot import name 'natsorted'`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, Not in western europe (except britain)

Comment: @Reman. Interesting how did you install it and what version are you using?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, 4.0.4. `pip install natsort`

Comment: @Reman, yep  brain fart, you can actually sort using `locale` once you have the appropriate locale installed, atof will handle the the conversion

Comment: Just as an FYI: https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort/issues/36. Hopefully that gets fixed. They the answer will be a single line. This is good for the library. I have used it a number of times with the default locale, never tried customizing before.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It was fixed as of ``natsort`` version 5.0.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use locale, just use `locale.atof` to cast after setting the locale to a suitable region:

```
In [6]: from locale import atof   
In [7]: import locale

In [8]: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
Out[8]: 'de_DE'

In [9]: mylist = ['23 text', '23.130', '12 text', '1.482 text', '3,250']

In [10]: sorted(mylist,key=lambda x: atof(x.split()[0]))
Out[10]: ['3,250', '12 text', '23 text', '1.482 text', '23.130']
```

If you can have just text, you can use a try/except, what you expect to happen for the string sort will decide what we do in the except, for now I just return float("inf") so the strings are pushed to the end:

```
from locale import atof
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')

mylist = ['23 text', '23.130', '12 text', '1.482 text', '3,250', "foo"]


def atof_try(x):
    try:
        return atof(x.split()[0])
    except ValueError:
        return float("inf")
```

So if we add `foo` to mylist:

```
In [35]: mylist = ['23 text', '23.130', '12 text', '1.482 text', '3,250', "foo"]

In [36]: sorted(mylist, key=atof_try)
Out[36]: ['3,250', '12 text', '23 text', '1.482 text', '23.130', 'foo']
```

Ok, bar the empty string at the end this matches your expected output, the regular sort would put the empty string at the end, we can change the if it really matters:

```
from locale import atof
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
import re

wrong_type = object()


def atof_try(x):
    try:
        return atof(x.split()[0])
    except ValueError:
        return wrong_type


def atof_pre(x, patt=re.compile("^\d+")):
    try:
        _atof = atof_try(x)
        if _atof is not wrong_type:
            return _atof
        temp = patt.search(x)
        return int(temp.group())
    except (ValueError, IndexError, AttributeError):
        return wrong_type


def merge_types(l, out):
    for ele in l:
        if atof_pre(ele) is not wrong_type:
            yield ele
        else:
            out.append(ele)
```

The output:

```
In [3]: temp = []

In [4]: mylist[:] = sorted(merge_types(mylist, temp), key=atof_pre) + sorted(temp)

In [5]: print(mylist)
['2 another test', '2apples', '4apples', '4,32', '4,32 hi', '12 today', '801', '13.300 a test', '', 'apples4', 'doo', 'foo']
```

Putting the logic in a class and doing an inplace sort on the odd list and extending in place of concatenation, you can pass in lambdas to specify what to sort on and `rev` determines if you reveres sort or not:

```
from locale import atof
import re


class WeirdSort:
    def __init__(self, in_list, rev=False, which=None, other=None):
        # holds all strings that don't match the pattern we want.
        self.temp = []
        self.in_list = in_list
        self.wrong_type = object()
        # what lambda to pass as the sort key.
        self.which = which
        # split data and sort in_list.
        self.in_list[:] = sorted(self.separate_types(), key=self.atof_pre, reverse=rev)
        # sort odd strings.
        self.temp.sort(key=other, reverse=rev)
        # merge both lists.
        if rev:
            self.temp.extend(self.in_list)
            self.in_list[:] = self.temp
        else:
            self.in_list.extend(self.temp)
        del self.temp

    def atof_try(self, x):
        """Try to cast using specified locale,
           return wrong_type on failure."""
        try:
            return atof(self.which(x))
        except ValueError:
            return self.wrong_type

    def atof_pre(self, x, patt=re.compile("^\d+")):
        """Try to cast using atof initially,
           on failure,  try to pull digits from
           front of string and cast to int.
           On failure, returns wrong_type object
           which will mean "x" will be sorted using a regular sort.
        """
        try:
            _atof = self.atof_try(x)
            if _atof is not self.wrong_type:
                return _atof
            temp = patt.search(x)
            return int(temp.group())
        except (ValueError, IndexError, AttributeError):
            return self.wrong_type

    def separate_types(self):
        """Separate elements that can be cast to a float
           using atof/int/re logic and those that cannot,
           anything that cannot be sorted will be
           added to temp_list and sorted separately.
        """
        for ele in self.in_list:
            if self.atof_pre(ele) is not self.wrong_type:
                yield ele
            else:
                self.temp.append(ele)
```

The empty string is also now at the end.

So for the input:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')

mylist = ['2 another test', '4,32', '801', '4apples', 'foo', '4,32 hi', 'apples4', '', '13.300 a test', '2apples', 'doo', '12 today']
flat_lambda1, flat_lambda2 = lambda x: x.split()[0], lambda x: (x == "", x)
WeirdSort(mylist, True, flat_lambda1, flat_lambda2)
print(mylist)
sublst_lambda1, sublist_lambda2 = lambda x: x[0].split()[0], lambda x: (x[0] == "", x[0])
WeirdSort(mylist, False, lambda x: x.split()[0], lambda x: (x == "", x))
print(mylist)

mylist = [['3,25', 1], ['12 text', 2], ["", 5], ['23 text', 3]]
WeirdSort(mylist, True, sublst_lambda1, sublist_lambda2)
print(mylist)
WeirdSort(mylist, False, sublst_lambda1, sublist_lambda2)
print(mylist)
```

You get:

```
['', 'foo', 'doo', 'apples4', '13.300 a test', '801', '12 today', '4,32', '4,32 hi', '4apples', '2 another test', '2apples']
['2 another test', '2apples', '4apples', '4,32', '4,32 hi', '12 today', '801', '13.300 a test', 'apples4', 'doo', 'foo', '']
[['', 5], ['23 text', 3], ['12 text', 2], ['3,25', 1]]
[['3,25', 1], ['12 text', 2], ['23 text', 3], ['', 5]]
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the solution of alecxe as well. Using locale seems to me a bit easier. Just one more question. I tried your solution adding just a text string to my list. This gives an error.

Comment: If you can have mixed types you have two options. If the text is always alpha we can handle that with an if, if that is not guaranteed then we need to use a try/except, add what you expect in such cases and I will add how to get around it

Comment: but this gives not the output as expected. It must be `['3,250', '12 text', '23 text', '1.482 text', '23.130', 'foo']` First sorting of numbers (please see you first example)

Comment: @Reman, yes sorry, I forgot to add `.split()[0]`, it will do the job now, what would should happen if `"bar"` was in there too?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham nice use of `locale` and good error-handling mechanism!

Comment: Padraic, thank you very much! Now it works. I waited to answer you because I noted that it still gave an error. I captured lines in a file to a list and one line was empty. There was an empty field in the list and that gave an error. Will it be easy to adapt it to empty fields as well?

Comment: @Reman, no prob, if you want to ignore empty lines you can filter with `if line.strip()` when you parse the lines of the file.

Comment: It does not a sorting of fields like '4peers', '2peers' or 'apples?

Comment: @Reman, so really you want all digits whether there is a space or not, i,e for the above 2,4,4 should be extracted for the sort?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, sorry not being clear. I just want to sort all lines as above in my example using numbers (at the start of the string). When there are no numbers any more a sort like the default sort (apples, apples2, apples4, peers) etc and leave empty lines at the end of the text. (As the alphanumeric sort indicated in my question but recognizing the thousand separators and decimals)

Comment: @Reman,can you stick those elements in a list and add the expected output to your question?

Comment: Done, excuse me again.

Comment: @Reman, no worries, what if there was `42apple`? do we consider all leading numbers in the sort and ignore trailing?

Comment: Tnx. :) '42apple' after '12 today' First all numbers then sorting of non numbers. Hope you don't have to adapt too much.

Comment: @Reman, I tried to incorporate all the conditions, they the code to see if we are nearly there and then we can worry about improvements and explanation!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108326/discussion-between-reman-and-padraic-cunningham).

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I tried to sort a file with a letter and number at every start of line without succes: `D8 
D40
D32
D4 
D73
D42
D78
D41
D99
D43
D9 
D87
E5 
G1` --> output:  `D32
D4 
D40
D41
D42
D43
D73
D78
D8 
D87
D9 
D99
E5 
G1`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, are you there?

Answer (score 3):

You can solve it with a *custom sorting function*:

```
>>> sorted(mylist, key=lambda item: float(item.split(" ", 1)[0].replace(".", "").replace(",", ".")))
['3,25', '12 text', '23 text', '1.482 text', '23.130']
```

where the `key` function in this case splits each item by a space, gets the first item, replaces a dot with an empty string and a comma with a dot, then converts the result into float.

---

There are assumptions made for this solution and it works for the provided sample data, you may need to tweak/improve it to work on your real data - for example, now it would fail if it could not make the conversion to `float`.

Comment: Alexce, thank you very much for your answer. I've learned new things thanks to you too.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but the [natsort](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort) library version 5.0.0 now respects the locale's thousands separator when calling `humansort`:

```
import natsort, locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'german')
mylist = ['23 text', '23.130', '12 text', '1.482 text', '3,25']
natsort.humansorted(mylist)
```

Comment: Hi, I just checked it with my list in question `mylist = ['', 'foo', 'doo', 'apples4', '13.300 a test', '801', '12 today', '4,32', '4,32 hi', '4apples', '2 another test', '2apples']` --> results: `['', '2 another test', '2apples', '4,32', '4,32 hi', '4apples', '12 today', '801', '13.300 a test', 'apples4', 'doo', 'foo']` ==> this is wrong: '4apples' must be before '4,32', '4,32 hi'

Comment: I tried locale 'german' and locale 'french', both the same results.

Comment: I would like to ask you one more question: `r=['4apples', '801', 'Foo', 'foo', 'Foo', 'bar', 'Bar']`  --> humansorted(r) = `['4apples', '801', 'bar', 'Bar', 'foo', 'Foo', 'Foo']` --> humansorted(r, alg=ns.IGNORECASE) = `['4apples', '801', 'bar', 'Bar', 'Foo', 'foo', 'Foo']`  How can I obtain this result? `['4apples', '801', 'Bar', 'bar', 'Foo', 'Foo', 'foo']`

Comment: @Reman I am pretty sure that the sort is stable (since this algorithm just generates keys for `sort`, which is stable based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/1915418/2988730), so you can try sorting twice: `humansorted(reverse(humansorted(r)), alg=ns.IGNORECASE)`. The first sort will group by case, then swap the order of the upper and lower case elements with `reverse`. The second sort will preserve the identical elements that only differ by case.

Comment: Mad Physicist, what about the sequence (my 1st comment)?

Comment: Mad, `so you can try sorting twice: humansorted(reverse(humansorted(r)), alg=ns.IGNORECASE)` --> this gives an error on my system (name 'reverse' is not defined)

Comment: Sorry, `reversed` is the built-in function. `reverse` is a method of `list`.

Comment: Thanks 'mad physicist'. Now I'm curious also to know how to resolve the sorting question (my 1st comment); `'4apples'` must be before `'4,32', '4,32 hi'`. Do you have any idea? (please see my question at the top of this page)

Comment: @Reman, It seems like you want to sort by floating point numbers.  You can do the following: `humansorted(r, alg=ns.REAL)`

Comment: @SethMMorton, you're right that is the solution but with `alg=ns.real` ignorecase (`alg=ns.ignorecase`) is not active anymore. Is it possible to use both (real & ignorecase) as key? I checked the natsort page but there was no example with multiple keys.

Comment: @Reman, aren't those just bit flags that you can combine with `|`?

Comment: @Reman Here is the documentation for how to combine multiple keys: http://pythonhosted.org/natsort/ns_class.html.  I will make sure I add an explicit example on the README.

Comment: The previous link will go dead in the near future. Here is the new home: natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/ns_class.html