# python sort list of lists with tie-breaker

Tags: python, list, sorting, sublist

What is the most pythonic way to sort a list of lists with a tie-breaker?

I can sort by sub-list length (longest to shortest):

```
>>> l = [['c'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]

>>> list(reversed(sorted(l, key=len)))
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], ['c']]
```

But I want to preserve order when the lengths are equal, so the output I want is:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c']]
```

Comment: Related: [Is python's sorted() function guaranteed to be stable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915376/is-pythons-sorted-function-guaranteed-to-be-stable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) (Python's built-in sorting algorithm) is stable, meaning it *keeps the original order* of elements with equal keys. However, you reversed the original order by using the `reversed` function.

If you want to reverse the resulting list *and* preserve the original order of elements comparing equal, use `reverse=True`:

```
In [3]: sorted(l, key=len, reverse=True)
Out[3]: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c']]
```

Comment: Good answer, I pass `reverse` an argument to `sorted` because it's more efficient than reversing the output of sorted, but I'd not considered that the final result could be different

Answer (score 0):

You could make a new list, paring each element with its position in the original list, then sort using that value as a secondary part of the key, and finally stripping the positions of for the final result.