# Multiple sorts by remembering previous sort

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a `list` in `python` as follows,

```
 l =    [['4K', ['read', '10'], ['rand', '70']],
        ['64K', ['read', '15'], ['rand', '0']],
        ['64K', ['read', '0'], ['rand', '0']],
        ['4K', ['read', '60'], ['rand', '100']],
        ['4K', ['read', '50'], ['rand', '0']]]
```

If `temp = ['4K', ['read', '10'], ['rand', '100']` I first want to sort based on `temp[2][1]`, after which I want to sort the list further without modifying the previous sort with respect to `temp[1][1]`. I want the end result to be something like follows,

```
res = [['64K', ['read', '0'], ['rand', '0']],
       ['64K', ['read', '15'], ['rand', '0']],
       ['4K', ['read', '50'], ['rand', '0']],
       ['4K', ['read', '10'], ['rand', '70'],
       ['4K', ['read', '60'], ['rand', '100']
      ]
```

In `res` above the priority is first given to `rand` which is sorted first, after which `read` is sorted with the sorted `rand`. I have tried things like `l.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[2][1]))` which first sorts the `rand`, but sorting the same `l` further does not give expected output as the previous sort is not remembered. Is there an easy way to do this? Or is the only way to this would be to split the list further with same `rand` and then sort and merge all together at the end?

Comment: @NickA I think the official term is "stable sort", which Python's built-in sort [already is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1915418/1639625). (The advice about applying the criteria backwards is valid, of course)

Comment: @tobias_k I've moved our discussion to an answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l.sort(key=lambda x: (int(x[2][1]), int(x[1][1])))
```

Does exactly what you want. Tuples are sorted giving priority in order.

Answer (score 1):

@Oersted's answer is the way to go however the general rule when sorting by multiple criteria is to sort using a [stable sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517793/stability-in-sorting-algorithms)([which pythons `list.sort` is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915376/is-pythons-sorted-function-guaranteed-to-be-stable/1915418#1915418)) and to sort through the criteria backwards, this rule can be used anywhere from sorting in excel to sorting a web based table, in this case you would use:

```
l.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[1][1]))
l.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[2][1]))
```

Comment: This approach also gets the job done... Thank you @Nick A