# Order of output changes for heapq.nlargest with a key function (Python)

Tags: python

Could someone please explain why does the order of output change when the `nlargest` function is called with a key function with only the first arg,

```
import heapq
heap_arr = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (3, 'd')]

heapq.nlargest(2, x)
# Perfectly fine - OP is [(3, 'd'), (3, 'c')]
# This is similar to heapq.nlargest(2, x, key=lambda a: (a[0], a[1]))

heapq.nlargest(2, x, key=lambda a: a[0])
# OP is [(3, 'c'), (3, 'd')]... Why ??
```

Why does (3, 'c') appear first in the second example before (3, 'd'). The reason behind this question is that the order of tuples in the output list is important.

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer:**

`heapq.nlargest(2, heap_arr)` returns `[(3, 'd'), (3, 'c')]` because

```
In [6]: (3, 'd') > (3, 'c')
Out[6]: True
```

`heapq.nlargest(2, heap_arr, key=lambda a: a[0])` returns `[(3, 'c'), (3, 'd')]`
because `heapq`, like `sorted`, uses a [stable sorting algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1517793/190597). Since the keys match (at the value 3) the stable sort returns the items in the order in which they appear in `heap_arr`:

```
In [8]: heapq.nlargest(2, [(3, 'c'), (3, 'd')], key=lambda a: a[0])
Out[8]: [(3, 'c'), (3, 'd')]

In [9]: heapq.nlargest(2, [(3, 'd'), (3, 'c')], key=lambda a: a[0])
Out[9]: [(3, 'd'), (3, 'c')]
```

---

**Longer Answer:**

[Per the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest), `heapq.nlargest(n, iterable, key)` is equivalent to

```
sorted(iterable, key=key, reverse=True)[:n]
```

(though `heapq.nlargest` computes its result in a different way). 
Nevertheless, we can use this equivalency to check that `heapq.nlargest` is behaving as we should expect:

```
import heapq
heap_arr = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (3, 'd')]

assert heapq.nlargest(2, heap_arr) == sorted(heap_arr, reverse=True)[:2]

assert heapq.nlargest(2, heap_arr, key=lambda a: a[0]) == sorted(heap_arr, key=lambda a: a[0], reverse=True)[:2]
```

So if you accept this equivalency, then you merely have to confirm the validity of

```
In [47]: sorted(heap_arr, reverse=True)
Out[47]: [(3, 'd'), (3, 'c'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (1, 'a')]

In [48]: sorted(heap_arr, key=lambda a: a[0], reverse=True)
Out[48]: [(3, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (1, 'a')]
```

When using `key=lambda a: a[0]`, `(3, 'c')`, `(3, 'd')` are sorted according to
the same key value, 3. Because [Python's sort is stable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1915376/190597), two items with equals
keys (e.g. `(3, 'c')` and `(3, 'd')`) appear in the result in the same order as
they appear in `heap_arr`.

---

**Even longer answer:**

To understand what is really going on [under the hood](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/heapq.py#L567), you could use a debugger or simply copy the code for heapq into a file and use print statements to study how the heap -- that is, the variable `result` -- changes as the elements in the iterable are examined and possibly pushed onto the heap. Running this code:

```
def heapreplace(heap, item):
    """Pop and return the current smallest value, and add the new item.

    This is more efficient than heappop() followed by heappush(), and can be
    more appropriate when using a fixed-size heap.  Note that the value
    returned may be larger than item!  That constrains reasonable uses of
    this routine unless written as part of a conditional replacement:

        if item > heap[0]:
            item = heapreplace(heap, item)
    """
    returnitem = heap[0]    # raises appropriate IndexError if heap is empty
    heap[0] = item
    _siftup(heap, 0)
    return returnitem

def heapify(x):
    """Transform list into a heap, in-place, in O(len(x)) time."""
    n = len(x)
    # Transform bottom-up.  The largest index there's any point to looking at
    # is the largest with a child index in-range, so must have 2*i + 1 < n,
    # or i < (n-1)/2.  If n is even = 2*j, this is (2*j-1)/2 = j-1/2 so
    # j-1 is the largest, which is n//2 - 1.  If n is odd = 2*j+1, this is
    # (2*j+1-1)/2 = j so j-1 is the largest, and that's again n//2-1.
    for i in reversed(range(n//2)):
        _siftup(x, i)

# 'heap' is a heap at all indices >= startpos, except possibly for pos.  pos
# is the index of a leaf with a possibly out-of-order value.  Restore the
# heap invariant.
def _siftdown(heap, startpos, pos):
    newitem = heap[pos]
    # Follow the path to the root, moving parents down until finding a place
    # newitem fits.
    while pos > startpos:
        parentpos = (pos - 1) >> 1
        parent = heap[parentpos]
        if newitem < parent:
            heap[pos] = parent
            pos = parentpos
            continue
        break
    heap[pos] = newitem


def _siftup(heap, pos):
    endpos = len(heap)
    startpos = pos
    newitem = heap[pos]
    # Bubble up the smaller child until hitting a leaf.
    childpos = 2*pos + 1    # leftmost child position
    while childpos < endpos:
        # Set childpos to index of smaller child.
        rightpos = childpos + 1
        if rightpos < endpos and not heap[childpos] < heap[rightpos]:
            childpos = rightpos
        # Move the smaller child up.
        heap[pos] = heap[childpos]
        pos = childpos
        childpos = 2*pos + 1
    # The leaf at pos is empty now.  Put newitem there, and bubble it up
    # to its final resting place (by sifting its parents down).
    heap[pos] = newitem
    _siftdown(heap, startpos, pos)


def nlargest(n, iterable, key=None):
    """Find the n largest elements in a dataset.

    Equivalent to:  sorted(iterable, key=key, reverse=True)[:n]
    """

    # Short-cut for n==1 is to use max()
    if n == 1:
        it = iter(iterable)
        sentinel = object()
        if key is None:
            result = max(it, default=sentinel)
        else:
            result = max(it, default=sentinel, key=key)
        return [] if result is sentinel else [result]

    # When n>=size, it's faster to use sorted()
    try:
        size = len(iterable)
    except (TypeError, AttributeError):
        pass
    else:
        if n >= size:
            return sorted(iterable, key=key, reverse=True)[:n]

    # When key is none, use simpler decoration
    if key is None:
        it = iter(iterable)
        result = [(elem, i) for i, elem in zip(range(0, -n, -1), it)]
        print('result: {}'.format(result))
        if not result:
            return result
        heapify(result)
        top = result[0][0]
        order = -n
        _heapreplace = heapreplace
        for elem in it:
            print('elem: {}'.format(elem))
            if top < elem:
                _heapreplace(result, (elem, order))
                print('result: {}'.format(result))
                top, _order = result[0]
                order -= 1
        result.sort(reverse=True)
        return [elem for (elem, order) in result]

    # General case, slowest method
    it = iter(iterable)
    result = [(key(elem), i, elem) for i, elem in zip(range(0, -n, -1), it)]
    print('result: {}'.format(result))
    if not result:
        return result
    heapify(result)
    top = result[0][0]
    order = -n
    _heapreplace = heapreplace
    for elem in it:
        print('elem: {}'.format(elem))
        k = key(elem)
        if top < k:
            _heapreplace(result, (k, order, elem))
            print('result: {}'.format(result))
            top, _order, _elem = result[0]
            order -= 1
    result.sort(reverse=True)
    return [elem for (k, order, elem) in result]


heap_arr = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (3, 'd')]

nlargest(2, heap_arr)
print('-'*10)
nlargest(2, heap_arr, key=lambda a: a[0])
```

yields

```
# nlargest(2, heap_arr)
result: [((1, 'a'), 0), ((2, 'b'), -1)]
elem: (2, 'b')
result: [((2, 'b'), -2), ((2, 'b'), -1)]
elem: (3, 'c')
result: [((2, 'b'), -1), ((3, 'c'), -3)]
elem: (3, 'd')
result: [((3, 'c'), -3), ((3, 'd'), -4)]      <---- compare this line (1)
----------

# nlargest(2, heap_arr, key=lambda a: a[0])
result: [(1, 0, (1, 'a')), (2, -1, (2, 'b'))]
elem: (2, 'b')
result: [(2, -2, (2, 'b')), (2, -1, (2, 'b'))]
elem: (3, 'c')
result: [(2, -1, (2, 'b')), (3, -3, (3, 'c'))]
elem: (3, 'd')
result: [(3, -4, (3, 'd')), (3, -3, (3, 'c'))] <---- with this line (2)
```

Remember that in a heap, `heap[0]` is always the smallest item. And indeed,

```
In [45]: ((3, 'c'), -3) < ((3, 'd'), -4)
Out[45]: True

In [46]: (3, -4, (3, 'd')) < (3, -3, (3, 'c'))
Out[46]: True
```

This justifies the result we are seeing on lines (1) and (2).
When the tuples are [undecorated](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#The_Old_Way_Using_Decorate-Sort-Undecorate), in the first case, (1), 
`(3, 'c')` ends up coming before `(3, 'd')` while in the second case, (2), 
the reverse happens.

So the behavior you are seeing arises from the fact that when `key is None`, the elements from the iterable are placed in the heap as though they were tuples of the form `(elem, order)` where the `order` decrements by 1 with every `_heapreplace`.
In contrast, when `key is not None`, the tuples are of the form `(k, order, elem)` where `k` is `key(elem)`. This difference in the form of the tuples leads to the difference you see in the result.

In the first case, `elem` ends up controlling the order.  In the second case,
since the `k` values are equal, `order` ends up controlling the order. *The
purpose of `order` is to break ties in a stable way*.  So ultimately we reach
the same conclusion as when we examined `sorted(heap_arr, key=lambda a: a[0],
reverse=True)`. The order of `(3, 'c')` and `(3, 'd')` is the same as their
order in `heap_arr` when the keys are equal.

If you want the ties in `a[0]` to be broken by `a` itself then use

```
In [53]: heapq.nlargest(2, heap_arr, key=lambda a: (a[0], a))
Out[53]: [(3, 'd'), (3, 'c')]
```