# Sort a list using a partial match in another list

Tags: python, list, sorting, partial

Consider this list.

```
input_list = ['Saturday', 'Tuesday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Thursday', 'Wednesday', 'Cheeseburger', 'Friday']
```

I want to sort it based on partial matches of a 2nd list.

```
list_sorter = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed']
```

so that

```
output_list = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Cheeseburger', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday','Thursday']
```

Storing the sorted list to input_list is preferred. Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Edit:

I've tried `sorted(input_list, key = list_sorter.index)`

Which errors.

> ValueError: 'Saturday' is not in list

I've tried `sorted(input_list, key = lambda x: x in list_sorter)`

Which is also not correct.

Edit 2: 
It should not be assumed the text is at the start of the word. Sorry for the late edit, it didn't occur to me until I saw the replies.

```
list_sorter = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'rida']
output_list = ['Monday', 'Tuesday','Friday','Cheeseburger', 'Saturday', 'Sunday','Thursday','Wednesday']
```

when there's a partial match on list_sorter should also be supported.

Comment: So, what have you tried? While some answerers might feel generous and answer anyway, you're much more likely to get an answer if you've tried to solve the problem yourself and can show your work (and what is going wrong with it). This question reads like a homework assignment, and Stack Overflow isn't here to do your homework for you. Hint: Try writing a function you can pass as `list.sort`'s `key` parameter.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your samples don't make too much sense to me. Please be clear about what you need.

Comment: it there a rule for words not concerned by list_sorter ?

Comment: Words not covered in the list_sorter I would like them to either be sorted alphabetically or preserved order. So I have control of the order. list_sorter ranks the input_list by most important first and remaining words are the same rank.

Comment: @Joylove, I updated my solution; the words not covered are in preserved order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a dictionary mapping, then use `sorted` with `dict.__getitem__`. This works fine because `sorted` is a [stable sorting algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915376/is-pythons-sorted-function-guaranteed-to-be-stable).

```
sort_map = {day: next((idx for idx, val in enumerate(list_sorter) if val in day),
                 len(input_list)) for day in input_list}

res = sorted(input_list, key=sort_map.__getitem__)

['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday',
 'Thursday', 'Wednesday', 'Cheeseburger']
```

Comment: it works because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6; perharps dangerous ?

Comment: @B.M., Nope, my solution does not rely on ordering of dictionaries. `sort_map` maps to integers, no `dict` ordering is assumed.

Comment: Ok I understood. I was troubled because 'Cheeseburger' was at is alphabetic place, but this is a random feature. So no problem.

Answer (score 1):

First make a dictionary with sorting informations in `O(len(list_sorter)+len(input_list))`:

```
order=dict.fromkeys([x[:3] for x in input_list],len(list_sorter))
order.update({k:v for (v,k) in enumerate(list_sorter)})
#{'Sat': 3, 'Tue': 1, 'Sun': 3, 'Mon': 0, 'Thu': 3, 'Wed': 2, 'Che': 3, 'Fri': 3}
```

Then sort:

```
res=sorted(input_list, key = lambda x : (order[x[:3]],x[:3]))
#['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Cheeseburger', 'Friday', \
#  'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Thursday']
```

Not covered words are at the end, in alphabetic order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you get the order of the unsorted item in your list so I assume they are unsorted.

Here's an example:

```
        input_list = ['Saturday', 'Tuesday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Thursday', 'Wednesday', 'Cheeseburger', 'Friday']
        list_sorter = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed']
        list_sorter.reverse()
        tupple_list = []
        for element in input_list:
            sub_string = element[0:3]
            if sub_string in list_sorter:
                index = list_sorter.index(sub_string) + 1
            else:
                index = 0
            tupple_list.append((element, index))
        sorted_list = sorted(tupple_list, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
        output_list = []
        for tupple in sorted_list:
            output_list.append(tupple[0])
        print (output_list)
```

Giving:

```
['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Thursday', 'Cheeseburger', 'Friday']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import partial

def keysort(value, lOrder):
    index = 10000
    for i, pmatch in enumerate(lOrder, 1):
        if value.upper().find(pmatch.upper())!=-1:
            index=i
            break
    return index

def main():
    list_sorter = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'rida']
    output_list = ['Thursday', 'Saturday', 'Tuesday', 'Friday', 'Cheeseburger', 'Monday', 'Sunday', 'Wednesday']
    slist = sorted(output_list, key=partial(keysort, lOrder=list_sorter))
    print (slist)
#['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Friday', 'Thursday', 'Saturday', 'Cheeseburger', 'Sunday', 'Wednesday']
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```