# Product of coordinates with specific order of iteration

Tags: python, cartesian-product

Here's a snippet with a regular `itertools.product` usage:

```
from itertools import product

arr = [1,2,3]
pairs = list(product(arr, arr))

# pairs = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Now I would like to have these points yielded in an order which can be achieved by sorting the resulting tuples in the following way:

```py
sorted(pairs, key=lambda y:max(y))
# [(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Is there a way for me to input those numbers to `itertools.product` so it yields the tuples in this order, or do I need to sort the pairs after iterating over the results of `itertools.product`?

Comment: the latter, you've got it right.

Comment: Please, clarify _I want the smallest numbers to appear first._

Comment: Yes, you need to sort the pairs, from the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product `product(A, B) returns the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in B).`

Comment: @sentence As specified in the question "I want the smallest numbers to appear first" is visualized just below using the `sorted` expression i.e. I want to have the tuples sorted by max() of their elements

Comment: `sorted` is [guaranteed to be **stable**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915376/is-pythons-sorted-function-guaranteed-to-be-stable), so your own attempt is correct assuming that the *input array itself is sorted*.

Comment: You could avoid the sort by generating them directly in the desired order, but I don't think anything off-the-shelf from itertools would accomplish that.  You'd need to write your own loops to do it.  It's probably not worth it unless `arr` is large enough for the sort time to be problematic.  You could also write a generator to produce the pairs in the desired order.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use your own modified approach to achieve this in one go.

```
sorted([(x, y) for x in [1, 2, 3] for y in [1, 2, 3]], key=lambda y:max(y))
```

**OUTPUT**

> [(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]