# Implementation of stable_sort in python

Tags: python, c++, stable-sort

In c++ there is a function stable_sort() function (It preserves the order ) .Is there any function in python like this ?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915376/is-pythons-sorted-function-guaranteed-to-be-stable. `sorted` function is guaranteed to be stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[list.sort()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) is stable.  From the documentation:

> The sort() method is guaranteed to be stable. A sort is stable if it guarantees not to change the relative order of elements that compare equal — this is helpful for sorting in multiple passes (for example, sort by department, then by salary grade).